# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm trying to format my GraphQL query using fragments, but I keep getting the error:

GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

```
const ItemFields = gql`
fragment ItemFields on Item {
  id
  title
  imageurl
  description
  createdon
  tags {
    id
    title
  }
  ownerid {
    id
    fullname
    email
    bio
  }
  borrower {
    id
    fullname
    email
    bio
  }
}
`;


export const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query item($filter: ID) {
    item {
      ...ItemFields
    }
  }
  ${ItemFields}
`;
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Can anyone advise me how to correct this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include the error message you are getting in the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Everything seems ok. It would help if you can post schema as well.

Comment: Did you end up finding the solution to this?

Comment: I've the same issue.